# got a unreachable statement on switch statment

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int day;
    int month = 5;
    int year = 2018;
    String str;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    day = s.nextInt();
    switch(day) {
        case 1:
            str = "Sunday";
        break;

        case 2:
            str = "Monday";
        break;

        case 3:
            str = "Tuesday";
        break;

        case 4:
            str = "Wednesday";
        break;

        case 5:
            str = "Thursday";
        break;

        case 6:
            str = "Friday";
        break;

        case 7:
            str = "Saturday";
        break;

     System.out.println(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Hello
Why I Keep get a error:

unreachable statement
         System.out.println(str);
OR I SOMETIMES GET variable str might not have been initialized
        System.out.println(str);
Thanks for help

Comment: move it one row below. it's still inside a `switch`

Comment: `System.out.println(str);` is inside `case 7`, after `break` statement...

Comment: Why the down votes? This is a valid and clear question. And if it looks stupid to others, remember, everyone started at some point in time and everyone had stupid errors you overlooked for hours.

Comment: @Korashen is not a stupid question, but is not a valid question for this site either. Check the reason to vote: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Hm.. yea... the typographical thing... yep, ok, I agree with that.

Comment: Don't think it's a typo-style question (I did at first, until I read more closely). The OP is caught between two different compilation errors and doesn't understand how to deal with it. More of an issue with not understanding how `switch` works.

Comment: Yes Guys , I am new in developing and I learn it alone so what? maybe stupid question for you guys but I dont know that ! but however thanks to anyone :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> unreachable statement System.out.println(str); OR I SOMETIMES GET variable str might not have been initialized

With what you have in your question, it's "unreachable statement" because the `System.out.println(str)` is within `case 7` after `break`, so it can't be reached.

If you move it to where it should be, after the closing `}` of the `switch`, you'll get the "variable str might not have been initialized" because that's true if `day` isn't any of the values in the `switch`'s `case`s, which it very well may not be as this is user input.

I'd put the `System.out.println(str);` after the `switch` and add a `default` to the switch:

```
default:
    throw new IllegalStateException("'day' cannot have the value " + day);
```

That will prevent both errors. (Or in your specific case, you may use a different exception, or just output a message and then `return;` to exit `main` since this is user input.)

Here's are those changes in situ, for clarity:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int day;
    int month = 5;
    int year = 2018;
    String str;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    day = s.nextInt();
    switch(day) {
        case 1:
            str = "Sunday";
        break;

        case 2:
            str = "Monday";
        break;

        case 3:
            str = "Tuesday";
        break;

        case 4:
            str = "Wednesday";
        break;

        case 5:
            str = "Thursday";
        break;

        case 6:
            str = "Friday";
        break;

        case 7:
            str = "Saturday";
        break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("'day' cannot be " + day);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: nice thorough explanation

Answer (score -1):

You got the error because your break statement exits the switch statement before reaching the sysout statement.

use the sysout outside of switch statement.

Comment: `break` doesn't terminate the program. It just exits the `switch` statement.

Comment: You still seem to be saying that the problem is that the *program exits*. That is not the problem.

Comment: As of the latest edit, you've explained what the reason is for *one* of the errors and how to fix it. But clearly the OP tried that, given the *other* error they asked about. Also: Please don't abuse blockquotes.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your valuable suggestion..I will try to maintain that in future... thanks :)

Comment: Thanks guys .. I got a solution